# Regex replace line feeds if they occur more than one time including combination with space in between

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

So i have a string that i want to replace all the line feeds that occur more than two times in a sequence by just one line feed. For this i use:

```
Regex.Replace(str, "(?:\r\n|\r(?!\n)|(?!<\r)\n){2,}", Environment.NewLine)
```

This works as long as the sequence is `\r\n\r\n` but i have a case where is see this `\r\n \r\n \r\n` So how can i replace those values using Regex?

Comment: I don't know if C# supports it but have a try with: `(?:\R\h*){2,}` where `\R` stands for any kind of linebreak and `\h` any horizontal spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?:(?:[ \t\r\n])+(?![\r\n]))+", Environment.NewLine);
```

Includes tab in addition to space.

Comment: This doesn't match `\n \n \n`

Comment: fixed to handle this case

Comment: Ah thanks, almost there because this also replaces the spaces between words. For example: "Hi there, this is the firstline\r\n \r\nAnd this is the second line" must be "Hi there, this is the firstline\r\nAnd this is the second line"